# 2D raster image line of sight algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, 2d

I'm working on a simple mapping application for fun, and one of the things I need to do is to find (and color) all of the points that are visible from the current location. In this case, points are pixels. My map is a raster image where transparent pixels are open space, and any other pixels are opaque. (There are no semi-transparent pixels; alpha is either 0 or 100%.) In this sense, it's sort of like a regular flood fill, with the constraint that each filled pixel has to have a clear line-of-sight to the origin point. The following image shows a couple of such areas colored in (the tiny crosshairs are the origin points, and white = transparent):

(http://tinyurl.com/nf3nqa4)

In addition, what I am ultimately interested in are the points that "border" other colors, i.e., I want the list of points that make up the edge of the visible region.

My current and very inefficient solution is the modified flood-fill I described above. This approach returns correct results, but due to the need to iterate every pixel on a line to the origin for every pixel in the flood fill, it's very slow. My images are downsized and quantized, but I still need about 1MP for acceptable accuracy, and typical LoS areas are at least 100,000 pixels each.

I may well be using the wrong search terms, but I haven't been able to find any discussion of algorithms that would solve this (rasterized) LoS case.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that this could be done more efficiently if your "walls" were represented as equations rather than simply pixels in a raster image.  For example, polygons/triangles, circles, ellipses.

It would then be like raytracing (search for this term) in 2D.  In other words, you could consider the ray/line from each pixel in the image to the point of interest and color the pixel only if it does not intersect with any object.

This method does require you to test the intersection for each pixel in the image with each object; however, if you look up raytracing you will find a number of efficient methods for testing these intersections.  They will mostly be for the 3D case but it should be straightforward to convert them to 2D.

There are 3D raytracers that are very fast on MUCH larger images so this should be very doable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I am familiar with ray tracing techniques, but unfortunately my input data is all from photographs, which I filter/quantize to generate transparent regions. Unlike the crude sample image I provided, the real regions are irregular shapes--not (in general) anything I could approximate with a small-ish number of polygons, ellipses, or curves. Or is there some other way to go about it?

Comment: @Luk232 I see, how does your current algorithm work?  Do you use Bresenham's?  Do you move around the edge/border of the image or check from every pixel?

Comment: @Luk232 Also, what do you mean by "points that border other colors?"  Do you mean the union of the borders of the line of sight across all points of interest?

Comment: Since there are only about 8300 possible different line slopes that fit my images (thanks to integer pixel coordinates), but over a million LoS lines to plot, I precompute the relative x/y offsets for each possible line (slope) so I don't need to calculate the line each time. Thus I check for collisions by just adding the current position to each element in the corresponding "slope" array, until I find something non-transparent.

Comment: To answer your second question, if you look at the sample image, the "border" I'm talking about for, say, the red region, would be the edges where the red pixels meet either white or black pixels. Not shown, but these edges could also be other previously-drawn LoS regions (the LoS detection should consider these existing regions opaque). The logic behind how the origin points (crosshairs) are chosen is complex and beyond the scope, here, but it basically results in about a dozen origin points being chosen for a given image, on average. Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

You can try a delaunay triangulation on each color. I mean you can try to find the shape of each color with DT.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I'm afraid I don't follow. I understand the DT algorithm, just not its application to my problem. Would you mind giving a little more detail for your idea?

Comment: I mean you can try to find the shape of each color with DT.